# Is a countvectorizer the same as tfidfvectorizer with use_idf=false?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As the title states: Is a `countvectorizer` the same as `tfidfvectorizer` with use_idf=false ? If not why not ?

So does this also mean that adding the `tfidftransformer` here is redundant ?

```
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
tweets_vector = vect.fit_transform(corpus)
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(tweets_vector)
tweets_vector_tf = tf_transformer.transform(tweets_vector)
```

Comment: check out in detail explanation here https://manjunathhiremathm.wixsite.com/portfolio/blog-1/countvectorizer-v-s-tfidfvector

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, they're not the same. `TfidfVectorizer` normalizes its results, i.e. each vector in its output has norm 1:

```
>>> CountVectorizer().fit_transform(["foo bar baz", "foo bar quux"]).A
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1]])
>>> TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(["foo bar baz", "foo bar quux"]).A
array([[ 0.57735027,  0.57735027,  0.57735027,  0.        ],
       [ 0.57735027,  0.        ,  0.57735027,  0.57735027]])
```

This is done so that dot-products on the rows are cosine similarities. Also `TfidfVectorizer` can use logarithmically discounted frequencies when given the option `sublinear_tf=True`.

To make `TfidfVectorizer` behave as `CountVectorizer`, give it the constructor options `use_idf=False, normalize=None`.

Comment: I am not sure if there was a change in the API after since the last post, but it's the `norm` parameter instead of `normalize`

Comment: @Fred Foo, really good explanation. I have just one question, the TfidfVectorizer does not normalize the term frequency vector when use_idf=True right? in other words, it does not carry out two normalization process: one for the tf and one for the tfidf but just one for the tfidf.

Answer (score 1):

As larsmans said, TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=False, normalize=None, ...) is supposed to behave the same as CountVectorizer.

In the current version (0.14.1), there's a bug where TfidfVectorizer(binary=True, ...) silently leaves binary=False, which can throw you off during a grid search for the best parameters. (CountVectorizer, in contrast, sets the binary flag correctly.) This appears to be [fixed](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/39b859b95eda679c07fa962d5b91d850ae5ff76c) in future (post-0.14.1) versions.